# Can't program error message for schedule of subjects (can't exceed "x" number of hours) - Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, schedule

I need some help with a project of mine made with Microsoft Access. It's an app to control students and classes. What I want to do is I want the app to see if I can't schedule more hours to a subject. Every subject has a goal of hours (example: Math has a goal of 20 hours, so I need to schedule 20 hours for that subject), if that goal is exceeded I want the app to give me an error. Right now I have 2 important tables: 1 with the subjects and 1 with the schedule information. In the subjects table I have "Duracao" (goal of hours for the subject). I want the program to count how many times the subject appears in the schedule table, and compare that number with "Duracao". I tried a lot of different methods with no success.

EDIT1:

Here's the table's structure -

[Schedule/Class Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0s7x.png)

[Subjects Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4AYh.png)

EDIT2:

I don't know if I am doing it wrong , but I can't make the DCount() function work. I tried many times, and I got 2 results: 1 - it doesn't count anything; 2 - it gives me syntax error (I searched a lot and the syntax is good, tried like 5 different types of writing, still the same).

Comment: Could you please provide screenshots of these two tables so that we might better understand the situation? I'm having trouble visualizing this.

Comment: Check [Método Application.DCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/access.application.dcount). This function can be used in VBA or in a query/form in Access as a calculated field. It will count how many records fulfill requirementes you specify. In your case, try to count how many times the subject appears in the schedule table and then compare it to `Duracao`

Comment: Assuming your subjects have a numeric ID field in the Subjects table, your Dcount should look like this, including the quotation marks around the return value and table name. Replace these with your actual field and table name and it should work.  Dcount(“SubjectID”, “Schedule_Table_Name”, “Subject ID = “ & me.SubjectID)

Comment: And if it isn't a numeric ID? The ID is "Short Text" because it uses letters and numbers.